# jquery set background gradient with image doesn't work with css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is working

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image:
 -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), 
  url('http://i.imgur.com/Hsban3N.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="deco">123</div>
```

but why when I try to set it using css() of jquery it doesn't seem working? No error in the console at all :

http://jsfiddle.net/xcso27zk/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are passing multiple javascript objects to the `css` method, but it only takes one javascript object with multiple name-value pairs. So like this:

```
$('#deco').css({
    'background-image': '-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,0)),color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65))), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': 'background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': '-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')'
});
```

with only one set of brackets

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support duplicate keys in a javascript object.

Comment: Duplicate property names cause a syntax error in ECMAScript 5 strict mode. ECMAScript 2015 removes the restriction, but still, the last property overrides the prior.  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Duplicate_property_names

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery 1.8.8 on, it prefixes for you, so all you'll need to type is

```
$('#deco').css({
    'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 100%), url(' + img + ')'
})
```

Also. If you type something like this

```
$('#deco').css({
    'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(80%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,.65))), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,       rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 100%), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': '   -moz-linear-gradient(top,       rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 100%), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': '     -o-linear-gradient(top,       rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 100%), url(' + img + ')', 
    'background-image': '        linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,.65) 100%), url(' + img + ')'
})
```

The object won't work like you desire in some browsers. You will simply rewrite 'background-image' 4 times, essentially writing useless code.

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support duplicate keys in a javascript object.

Even in  Chrome, given value = { foo: 0, foo: 1 }; 
Object.keys(value) returns ['foo']
value['foo'] === 1

The first value, 0, is replaced by the second, 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only use jQuery's vendor prefixing for property names.  It never attempts to prefix anything in the value.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's css function doesn't accept a set of objects in a single call.

Instead of

```
$(...).css({},{},{})
```

Try

```
$(...).css({})
  .css({})
  .css({})
```

```js
var img = 'http://i.imgur.com/Hsban3N.jpg';

$('#deco').css({
'background-image': '-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')'
}).css({
'background-image': '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,0)),color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65))), url(' + img + ')'
}).css({
'background-image': '-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')'
}).css({
'background-image': '-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')'
}).css({
'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0)80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%), url(' + img + ')'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="deco">123</div>
```

Comment: It does accept one object with multiple properties, though. So having a lot of `.css()`s isn't necessary

Comment: In this case, it's required. Because the property name is the same in each .css call, we're unable to combine them into a single multi-property call.

Comment: It still isn't required, because having multiple `.css()` calls with the same property will only just override the previous ones

Comment: each rule is conditionally accepted by the browser which is required for cases like multiple vendor prefixes.  the last one accepted as valid by the browser is the one that sticks

Comment: Didn't know about that! Does this also work for the two `-webkit-` ones?

Comment: It would appear this works for the whole rule.  If the browser can't apply the value, it doesn't change the property. It's the behavior that allows graceful degradation.

By putting the newest implementation last, you don't override it with the older, more broadly implemented version.  i.e.  Start with standard, then use experimental or vendor, if the vendor rule doesn't stick, it falls back to the standard rule

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did this and it seems to be working fine on both FF and Chrome.

```
var img = $(".stall-banner-img").val();
  $(".stall-page-banner").css({
    'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(82, 75, 75, 0.5)80%,rgba(34, 32, 32, 0.5)100%), url(' + img + ')'
  });
```